# Probability of two independent standard normal random variables

Tags: probability

Suppose we have $X,Y$, two independent standard normal random variables. How can we calculate

$P(|\min(X,Y)|<1)$.

---

I am still learning multivariables probability, and I also realize there are a lot of nice properties of two standard normal r.vs but I am not sure how to use them.

Comment: Hint: graph the relevant zone in the XY plane

Comment: Draw a sketch of the plane with coordinate axes $x$ and $y$, and mark on it the region described as $$\{(x,y) \colon |\min(x,y) | < 1\}.$$  _Then_ think of probabilities, not before you have finished the sketch.

Comment: I did. And I got a L-shape graph but I don't know how to start from here.

Comment: **Hint**: $\mathbb P(|\min(X,Y)| < 1)  = \mathbb P( \min(X,Y) > -1 ) - \mathbb P( \min(X,Y) \geq 1 )$. Can you continue from there?

Comment: Further hint on the L-shaped region.  It can be partitioned into two rectangular regions and you can find the probability that $(X,Y)$ belongs in each, and add.  The two probabilities are different.  Or you can use express the region as $A\cup B$ where $P(A) = P(B)$ and use $P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any continuous distribution:

$\Pr(|\min(X,Y)| \lt k) =  \Pr(\min(X,Y) \gt -k) -  \Pr(\min(X,Y) \ge k)$

$= \Pr(X \gt -k) \Pr(Y \gt -k) - \Pr(X \ge k) \Pr(Y \ge k)$

$ = (1- F(-k))^2- (1- F(k))^2 $.

In the case of a distribution which is symmetric about $0$, this reduces to

$F(k)^2- (1- F(k))^2= 2F(k)-1 = F(k)-F(-k) = \Pr(|X| \le k)$.

which is your result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to try to answer my own question.

Basically, when you try to graph the inequality of $|\min(X,Y)|<1$, you will get a L-shape graph. And the area of the function can be calculated as the following

$\begin{align}

\operatorname{Area}(|\min(X,Y)|<1) &= \operatorname{Area}(-1<X<1 \text{ and } Y >-1) + \operatorname{Area}(-1<Y<1 \text { and } X>1)\\
&=\operatorname{Area}(-1<X<1 \text{ and } Y>-1) + \operatorname{Area}(-1<X<1 \text { and } Y>1)\\
&=\operatorname{Area}(-1<X<1)
\end{align}$

It is like rotating the lower right piece of that L-shape graph 90 degrees clockwise.

Then the probability of $P(|\min(X,Y)|<1)$ can be easily calculated.

$P(|\min(X,Y)|<1) = P(-1<X<1) = \Phi(1)-\Phi(-1)$

Comment: Your intuition is correct but you should be careful about how you write up the solution, since the _areas_ of the regions are not finite.  Write the same thing in terms of the _probabilities_ (and add another line to go from $P\{-1 < X < 1, Y > 1\}$ to $P\{-1 < X < 1, Y < -1\}$ so that $$P\{-1 < X < 1, Y > -1\}+ P\{-1 < X < 1, Y < -1\} = P\{-1 < X < 1\}$$ is immediately obvious, and I will be glad to upvote your answer.